# How can I exclude package private class using Class Diagram Options?

Tags: javadoc, umlgraph

I trying to generate UML Graph with Javadoc using [UMLGraph](http://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/).

I'm searching an option on [here](http://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/doc/cd-opt.html) for excluding my package-private class from being visualized.

```
// package-private
// javadoc excludes it. that's ok.
// umlgraph keeps it. that's not ok.
class SomeBase {
}
```

The class is excluded from the Javadoc. But UMLGraph keeps it.

How can I, with what option, exclude the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see UMLGraph having such an option.  Consider adding the `@hidden` tag to the class's Javadoc comment as documented [here](http://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/doc/cd-opt-spec.html).